# Reliable Web API for requesting Time

Tags: web-services, time

Having read a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176418/leap-in-time-in-phps-function-time) about the reliability of the PHP `time` function, I wondered if there was some kind of 'reliable' web API to retrieve time from.

Comment: (I promise to not go for the 100 rep bounty with your answers)

Comment: I don't know any off the top of my head, but what you're looking for is a NTP API (Network Time Protocol).  And it should probably have an Atomic Clock Sync.  Hopefully this can point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does it have to be a web API? Typically you'd use [NTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) instead. It's a well-established protocol with plenty of freely accessible servers. It's usually used for synchronization rather than obtaining the time once though. But if you use something similar to keep your system clock accurate, then accessing the time from something like PHP should be okay.

Could you explain more about exactly what problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 2):

You may take a look at the [NIST Internet Time Service](http://tf.nist.gov/service/its.htm) and the [NTP Pool Project](http://www.pool.ntp.org/en/).